# TPS61090 LBI Pin-->frequency compensating capacitor for voltage divider?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider, parasitic-capacitance

I was reverse-engineering some PCB to gain knowledge how to apply a TPS61090 Boost Converter (see my schematics attached, sorry for the unusual "arrangement" of the components). Input VBAT is about 4.2V from a MCP73871 charger, which in turn receives the voltage either from a 3.7V LiPo battery or 5V USB plug.
I stumbled on C14. It seems to be some kind of capacitor for frequency compensation of the voltage divider. Even with greatest parasitic capacitance I see no reason for this, as LBIs only purpose is to deceide if voltage is below or above 500mV to switch the LBO. I could only imagine, that there will be some kind of delay, until the voltage at LBI reaches its maximum, what would be negligible I think. Or would it perhaps prevent a "flickering" LED, when VBAT ist near the defined region for LBO?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I've been adding a picture of the switch, which pulls the EN Pin of TPS61090 high to start up. Another question came up there regarding to C3, which is counterintuitively connected to VBAT instead of GND. As far as I understand, the switch works as follows:
Connecting PIN1 and PIN2 of S1 (momentary switch), EN gets pulled high. Releasing it, LED_POWER overtakes the task of supplying EN with voltage (EN_POWER is connected to a GPIO of a Raspberry Pi, which in turn gets powered, when TPS61090 starts up). For this small transition time between both conditions, the capacitor stores the charge to keep EN pulled up. But wouldn't that be the case if beeing connected to GND?
(Further, by switching S1 a second time, "SHUTDOWN", which is connected to a GPIO as well, gets pulled high to shut the Raspberry Pi down via script).

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only purpose is to filter the LBI line to reject noise.

Comment: Ah, nervermind, if the capacitor would be connected to GND, then pulling EN or SHUTDOWN high wouldn't be possible...But is my supposed purpose, a charge reservoir for the transition time, right?